# While loop not working as intended. Google script

Tags: while-loop

I am very new at programming in Google Script, and need some guidance here.

I have a loop that is supposed to check the value of a range, then move down to the next row and set the new range's value as "next", which is then compared to "team".

If the condition is met then "team" is given the same value from the range that "next" was given, and "next" is given the value of the range below the current one.

The purpose is to find how many entries there are that meet conditions in a column, then my other parts of the code manipulate that data.

When the "team" value isn't the same as "next" (the value of the range below the current one), then the loop is supposed to stop, but doesn't. Code:

```
while (team = next) {
  team = orange.getValue();
  row ++; 
  range = col + row.toString();
  orange = ordered.getRange(range);
  next = orange.getValue();
  entries ++;
  };
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When posting questions, please keep in mind that it is often hard to read one big block of text. Breaking up your question into separate paragraphs is usually the way to go.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Script, but do you have a way to message box(aka "pop-up" or write to terminal or even to a scratch column) the value of team and next at the end of each iteration of the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Google Script either, but most languages require double equal sign for equality tests.  From a cursory view I think Google Script uses the same syntax.  Try doing this instead:

```
while (team == next)
```

Notice the double `==` to check for equality instead of single `=` to assign a variable.